# Migrated hosting but DNS not updating in local pc

Tags: networking, dns, wireless-router, webserver, website

I recently changed hosting server for a website that I manage. When I do dns check using online dnschecker I can see that the new server IP address is shown. But when I ping from local pc it is showing the old IP and in browser pointing to old server.

```
ipconfig /flush dns
```

Gives following

> Windows IP Configuration
>
> Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.

But still I go to the old server when visiting and get old IP when pinging. Is there no way to force local machine to update it's DNS IP.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Yes tried that as well. Tried different browser. Also cmd is not related to browser cache. Still ping gives old ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be your router / upstream dns caching it.

Try using nslookup and a few external servers.

For example:
`nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8` 
Will check address www.google.com on dns server 8.8.8.8

Dns usually needs a bit of time to propagate, and depending on settings it might take a few hours.

Comment: I changed DNS value to 8.8.8.8 in my ipv4 settings. That fixed the issue.